# How to use BigInteger?

Tags: java, biginteger

I have this piece of code, which is not working:

```
BigInteger sum = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
for(int i = 2; i < 5000; i++) {
    if (isPrim(i)) {
        sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    }
}
```

The sum variable is always 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By the way, the sum should easily fit in `int`, so you don't need `BigInteger` for this example.

Comment: Nope, I changed the code. The number is bigger than 5000.

Comment: The question linked as duplicate does not seem to have the same problem as this question (the linked question is about *which* function to use so BigInteger can be added, this one is about *how* to use the add function)

Answer (score 207, accepted):

`BigInteger` is immutable.  The javadocs states that [**add()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#add-java.math.BigInteger-) "[r]eturns a BigInteger whose value is (this + val)." Therefore, you can't change `sum`, you need to reassign the result of the `add` method to `sum` variable.

```
sum = sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
```

Comment: int will be enough as long as you don't go over 2^31-1, long will be enough as long as you don't go over 2^63-1.

Comment: Which, in his example, he won't.

Comment: But is it really that hard to think perhaps he simplified his example down to exactly what the problem is?

Comment: @thecoshman - You are quite correct and the number of upvotes on your comment show this is wise advice for all readers of such questions. Some more wise advice is "**read what others wrote before answering or commenting.**" For example in this case it doesn't even require *ANY* thought since the OP clearly stated that he did just that in the comments below the Question: "*Nope, I changed the code. The number is bigger than 5000.*"

Answer (score 58):

```
sum = sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf(i))
```

The `BigInteger` class is immutable, hence you can't change its state. So calling "add" creates a new `BigInteger`, rather than modifying the current.

Answer (score 23):

Other replies have nailed it; BigInteger is immutable.  Here's the minor change to make that code work.

```
BigInteger sum = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
for(int i = 2; i < 5000; i++) {
    if (isPrim(i)) {
        sum = sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

BigInteger is an immutable class. So whenever you do any arithmetic, you have to reassign the output to a variable.

Answer (score 12):

`java.math.BigInteger` is an **immutable** class so we can not assign new object in the location of already assigned object. But you can create new object to assign new value like:

```
sum = sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's Immutable

```
sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
```

so the method add() of BigInteger class does not add new BigIntger value to its own value ,but **creates and returns a new BigInteger reference** without changing the current BigInteger and **this is what done even in the case of Strings**

Answer (score 0):

`Biginteger` is an immutable class. 
You need to explicitly assign value of your output to sum like this:

```
sum = sum.add(BigInteger.valueof(i));
```

Comment: This is now the 8th answer with the same explanation, so how is this answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose sometimes our input value is too big to store integer value eg.123456789123456789
In that case, standard datatype like long can't handle it. But Java provides a class "BigInteger". It helps us to pass and access huge value.
Please see the below exam to clear the concept.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        BigInteger B1=new BigInteger("10");
        BigInteger B2=new BigInteger("20");
        B1=sc.nextBigInteger();
        B2=sc.nextBigInteger();
        Solution obj=new Solution();
        obj.Big_Int(B1,B2);
        sc.close();
    }
    
    public void Big_Int(BigInteger a,BigInteger b)
    {
        //BigInteger bi=new BigInteger("1");
        BigInteger bi=BigInteger.TEN;
        bi=a;
        bi=bi.add(b);
        System.out.println(bi);
        bi=a;
        bi=bi.multiply(b);
        System.out.println(bi);
        
    }
}
```

input:
123456789123456789
1578426354785

output:
123458367549811574
194867449629598334799730885365

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can use,

```
BigInteger sum= new BigInteger("12345");
```

for creating object for BigInteger class.But the problem here is,you cannot give a variable in the double quotes.So we have to use the **valueOf()** method and we have to store the answer in that sum again.So we will write,

```
sum= sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
```

Comment: You have not identified the problem in the OP’s code.

Answer (score -6):

Since you are summing up some int values together, there is no need to use BigInteger. `long` is enough for that. `int` is 32 bits, while `long` is 64 bits, that can contain the sum of all int values.

Comment: "But is it really that hard to think perhaps he simplified his example down to exactly what the problem is?" (quoting thecoshman)

Comment: For this question, my answer is a bit our of scope. Since the topic focus on how to use BigInteger. Just one of my personal experience, if we want to sum up some integers and the numbers are not pretty big, I would prefer long. Because that's easy to use and runs faster. For large scale input, BigInteger is the good choice.