# Problems with BigInteger

Tags: java, biginteger

For some reason, BigInteger isn't working as I'd like. I'm doing BigVariable.add(BigVariable), but it won't add. It the result is always the value it's initialized to. Anyone know what I'm missing? Thanks in advance

The code is for project euler 48

```
import java.math.BigInteger;


public class tuna {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger result = BigInteger.ZERO;
    for(int i= 1; i <= 1000; i++)
        result.add( bigPow(BigInteger.valueOf(i), i) );
    System.out.println(result);
}
public static BigInteger bigPow(BigInteger number, int pow){
    if(pow < 1)
        throw new RuntimeException("bigPow can't handle exponents lower than 1");
    if (pow == 1)
        return number;
    return number.multiply( bigPow(number, pow-1) );
}

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: How to use BigInteger?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783912/java-how-to-use-biginteger)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
result = result.add( bigPow(BigInteger.valueOf(i), i) );
```

instead of:

```
result.add( bigPow(BigInteger.valueOf(i), i) );
```

You need to do this because BigInteger is immutable ([Immutable arbitrary-precision integers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)). So you need to reassign the result.

**add**

> public BigInteger add(BigInteger val)
>
> Returns a BigInteger whose value
> is (this + val). Parameters: val - value to be added to this
> BigInteger. Returns: this + val

Comment: You sir, are very smart. Thank you for the help. For some reason I thought BigVarible.function() was passed by reference.