# use sum and multiplication of a BigInteger

Tags: java, arraylist, biginteger

I've come across a situation where I have to perform sum and multiplication of the elements of an `ArrayList` and for this normally I use:

```
sum+=a.get(i)*b.get(i);
```

which gives me the exact output I want, but here in my case I've got to do the same with `ArrayList` of `BigInteger` type, I've tried it with the below statement, but it is not working as expected.

```
sum=(a.get(i).multiply(b.get(i))).add(sum);
```

please let me know how I can do it.

Thanks.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: What's wrong with your output?

Comment: Looks OK for me, but maybe you get your object-references mixed up - but we'll need more context to judge this.

Comment: a and b both are ArrayList right..? and what abt sum variable.?

Comment: "it is not working as expected"  This tells us nothing.  What did you expect and what is it doing?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that statement.

Comment: Sorry guys, i was printing the wrong loops. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is extremely unclear, and as such shouldn't warrant an answer. However, see if the following might help you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger("1000"), b2 = new BigInteger("1000");
    System.out.println("b1:      " + b1);
    System.out.println("b1 * b2: "+ b1.multiply(b2));
}
```

Also ensure that you are not falling into the [following pit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783912/java-how-to-use-biginteger?rq=1). BigInteger is immutable.

Answer (score 0):

```
BigInteger sum = new BigInteger("10");
List<BigInteger> list = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
list.add(new BigInteger("2"));
list.add(new BigInteger("3"));
sum=(list.get(0).multiply(list.get(1))).add(sum);
System.out.println(sum);
```