# Fibonacci calculation in Java Longs shows up negative

Tags: java, integer, long-integer, fibonacci

My Fibonacci calculator works fine, but when going up to higher numbers the result comes up negative, as it would if it was an `Integer` over its max value.

It is working with a cache `java.util.Map<Integer, Long>`. Everything that goes into the `Map` is exactly what is expected, but when printing it out I get e.g. for 291:

```
-784134397488903422
```

According to http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibCalcX.html, it should be:

```
2923602405716568564338475449381171413803636207598822186175234
```

It seems something goes wrong with my `Long`s, but I am not sure yet, what exactly. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Values of the `Map` entries:
http://pastebin.com/uje07Ays

Comment: `Long` overflowed. Use `BigInteger` instead.

Comment: Check java.lang.Long.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: You can see very nicely negative numbers occurring after the 92nd Fibonacci number. Compare this with java.lang.Long.MAX_VALUE...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are above the maximum long value that can be stored in a signed 64 bits integer used by Java for the long type, more information about Long and thesein the Java API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html.

The maximum positive value for a 64 bits signed integer is 2^63 -1: `9 223 372 036 854 775 807`, your value seems to have reach this limit and if the highest bit of a signed integer is 1, then the signed integer become negative (see 2 complement integer for more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

You need to use BigInteger to have arbitrary-precision integers http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html.

Comment: @laune you are right BigInteger must be used in this case. I have edited my answer in this way.

Comment: Thank you all very much! Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 0):

java has 8 [primitive data types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

#### byte

- Minimum value is -128 (-2^7)
- Maximum value is 127 (inclusive)(2^7 -1)
- Default value is 0

#### short

- Minimum value is -32,768 (-2^15)
- Maximum value is 32,767 (inclusive) (2^15 -1)
- Default value is 0.
- Short data type can also be used to save memory as byte data type. A short is 2 times smaller than an int ( but java change this type to int for calculation )

#### int

- Minimum value is - 2,147,483,648.(-2^31)
- Maximum value is 2,147,483,647(inclusive).(2^31 -1) , which is more than your number
- Int is generally used as the default data type for integral values
  unless there is a concern about memory.
- The default value is 0.

#### long

- Minimum value is -9,223,372,036,854,775,808.(-2^63)
- Maximum value is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (inclusive). (2^63 -1) this value is less than your number
- This type is used when a wider range than int is needed.
- Default value is 0L.

#### float

- Float data type is a single-precision 32-bit IEEE 754 floating point.
- Float is mainly used to save memory in large arrays of floating point
  numbers. using this type for int value is crime
- Default value is 0.0f.

#### double

- double data type is a double-precision 64-bit IEEE 754 floating
  point.
- This data type is generally used as the default data type for decimal
  values, generally the default choice.
- Double data type should never be used for precise values such as
  currency.
- Default value is 0.0d.

#### boolean

- boolean data type represents one bit of information.
- There are only two possible values: true and false.
- This data type is used for simple flags that track true/false
  conditions.
- Default value is false.

#### char

- har data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character.
- Minimum value is '\u0000' (or 0).
- Maximum value is '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).
- Char data type is used to store any character.

as you can see none of the above types can store your value so you had to use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783912/java-how-to-use-biginteger)) or any other class that can handle this big values.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer!

Comment: I haven't enough reputation to add comment :( @laune

Comment: This way you won't increase your rep. You are just repeating older comments.

Comment: there is no comment when I write my answer and I want to help him

Comment: @laune I edit my answer and this isn't seem to be comment any more

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Map<Integer, BigDecimal> fibonacciMap = new HashMap<Integer, BigDecimal>();
        fibonacciMap.put(1, BigDecimal.valueOf(1));
        fibonacciMap.put(2, BigDecimal.valueOf(1));
        System.out.println(1 + " : " + fibonacciMap.get(1));
        System.out.println(2 + " : " + fibonacciMap.get(2));

        for(int i=3;i<=300;i++)
        {
            fibonacciMap.put(i, fibonacciMap.get(i-1).add(fibonacciMap.get(i-2)));
            System.out.println(i + " : " + fibonacciMap.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Since, Maximum value for long in java is 9223372036854775807. So, when the fibonacci number goes above this max value, it start rounding of from -9223372036854775808(Min Value) to zero to 9223372036854775807(Max Value). So, we need to use BigDecimal instead of Long to avoid -ve values.

for example:

Fib[92]=7540113804746346429

Fib[91]=4660046610375530309

(BigDecimal)Fib[93]=Fib[91]+Fib[92]=12200160415121876738 which is greater than Long.MAX_VALUE

(Long)Fib[93]= -6246583658587674878

Long.MAX_VALUE = 9223372036854775807

Long.MIN_VALUE = -9223372036854775808

So,
(BigDecimal)Fib[93] = Long.MAX_VALUE - (Long.MIN_VALUE - (Long)Fib[93]) + 1;

Comment: Could you provide a comment on your solution, and describe what the problem was?

Comment: Since, Maximum value for long in java is 9223372036854775807. So, when the fibonacci number goes above this max value, it start rounding of from -9223372036854775808(Min Value) to zero to 9223372036854775807(Max Value). So, we need to use BigDecimal instead of Long to avoid -ve values.