# BigInteger mathematical functions not returning expected values

Tags: java, math, biginteger

I have a `BigInteger` method which takes a `string[]` array input of 4 numbers, converts the numbers into an `int[]`, and then applies numerous mathematical operations to it.

```
public BigInteger convert32Bit(String[] array)
{
    System.out.println("Array being converted is "+Arrays.toString(array)+"\n");
    int[] tempArray = new int[array.length];
    ArrayList<BigInteger> tempBigIntList = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
    int i = 0;
    for(String s:array)
    {
        int power = 4-i;
        tempArray[i]= Integer.parseInt(s);
        String string = Integer.toString(tempArray[0]);
        BigInteger myBigInt = new BigInteger(string);
        BigInteger num2 = myBigInt.multiply(new BigInteger("256").pow(power));
        System.out.println(tempArray[i]+" is being multiplied by 256^"+power+" which equals "+num2);
        tempBigIntList.add(num2);
        i++;
    }

    BigInteger bigInt32Bit = new BigInteger("0");
    for(BigInteger bI:tempBigIntList)
    {
        bigInt32Bit.add(bI);
    }

    System.out.println("\nThe final value is "+bigInt32Bit);

    return bigInt32Bit;
}
```

However there is a problem. If I take the array `"123", "0", "245", "23"` as the input. I get the following output.

[image: Wrong output]

The output I am expecting is

```
Array being converted is [123, 0, 245, 23]

123 is being multiplied by 256^4 which equals 528280977408
0 is being multiplied by 256^3 which equals 0
245 is being multiplied by 256^2 which equals 16056320
23 is being multiplied by 256^1 which equals 5888

The final value is 528297039616
```

Can someone please help fix this?

Comment: In your loop your `String string = Integer.toString(tempArray[0]);` should be `tempArray[i]`

Comment: @justhalf Thank you. That fixed the working out the values problem

Comment: Why the close votes?

Comment: If it's just a typo, this question should be closed as it will likely not help future readers. But since you have the confusion on the immutability of `BigInteger`, I think this question is quite ok.

Comment: @Dan, because this question is unlikely to be helpful for further visitors. You should not worry about this as your problem is actually solved.

Comment: Fair enough reasoning

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783912/java-how-to-use-biginteger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this line

```
bigInt32Bit.add(bI);
```

with

```
bigInt32Bit = bigInt32Bit.add(bI);
```

You do this because `BigInteger` is [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object#Java). This means that you have to create a new value for `bigInt32Bit` instead of just adjusting an old one. Also (as [@justhalf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/895932/justhalf) says) replace the line

```
String string = Integer.toString(tempArray[0]);
```

with

```
String string = Integer.toString(tempArray[i]);
```

so that you use the correct value when applying the mathematical operators.

Comment: Also there is a typo in his code, where `String string = Integer.toString(tempArray[0]);` should be `tempArray[i]` instead of `tempArray[0]`

Comment: Thank you both of you. Fixed the problems :)

Comment: @TagirValeev: Actually you don't need to change it to community wiki, it's just a small typo =)

Answer (score 0):

BigInteger is immutable and hence `bigInt32Bit.add(bI);` would lead the value of whatever you have first element. Inorder to add all the values you could do something like:

```
 bigInt32Bit = bigInt32Bit.add(bI);//assign it
```

Also you are just passing very first element of your array as input to bigInteger like `String string = Integer.toString(tempArray[0]);`, it should be `String string = Integer.toString(tempArray[i]);`. I would not use array if its not used anywhere insteadi would just use an integer variable.