# String to BigInteger in Java

Tags: java, string, biginteger

This is my code:

```
public class sample {
   public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {

      System.out.println("Enter from file:");

      BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\KK\\A Key.txt"));

      String currentline;

      while((currentline=br.readLine())!=null){

         System.out.println(currentline);
      }

      BigInteger a = new BigInteger(currentline); 

      System.out.println(a);

  }
```

I want to read from the text document , convert it into big integer from a string, I tried this but i get a run time error , How to convert String into corresponding Big integer Ascii value.

Comment: If you are running into an Excpetion and are asking what to do, it wont harm to include the exception in the question. Please do so.

Comment: The process is correct but I guess when you try to convert the String the value of currentline is null and you might be getting a NullPointerException there.

Comment: using constructor you can do this

Comment: @DurgpalSingh What is that supposed to mean? What constructor?!

Comment: You are not appending to the currentline variable, and when loop exits currentline variable will have "null" value and I am assuming you are getting NullPointerException. 
Try to append with new StringBuilder and then you the BigInteger class.

Comment: @DurgpalSingh: Krishna is *using* the constructor. It's right there in the code, big as life.

Comment: @zstring: There's an answer in there, well observed!

Comment: yes you are right @GhostCat

Comment: The clever thing here: he avoided the immediate "close as duplicate" to "whats a NPE and how do i fix it" by not posting his exception stack trace.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: How to use BigInteger?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783912/java-how-to-use-biginteger)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is very simple: you build a BigInteger from a null string!

You are looping **until** currentLine is **null**.

**Afterwards** you try to create a BigInteger from that!

Simply move things **into** your loop:

```
while((currentLine=br.readLine())!=null) {           
 System.out.println(currentLine);
 BigInteger a = new BigInteger(currentline); 
 System.out.println(a);
}
```

Et voilà, things are working (assuming that you expect each line in your file to be a number). If the whole file represents **one** number, then you must do as zstring suggests in his comment: you would have to use a StringBuilder for example to "collect" all lines into a **single** string that you then use to create the BigInteger object.

And please note java coding styles: class names start Uppercase; and variable names use camelCase (thus I changed to `currentLine`).

But just for the record: you wrote a low quality question. You should always include compiler error messages or stack traces when asking "why is my code not working".